# Make grid-template-columns dynamic

Tags: css, css-grid

I have a table whose some columns are created depends on data. I want to put those columns of fixed size between two specific columns.

And I'm implementing this like:

```css
.grid {
  width: 290px;
  overflow-x: auto;

  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: [index] 80px repeat(auto-fit, minmax(161px, auto)) [price] 210px
}

.col {
  grid-row: 1;
}

.col.index {
  grid-area: index;
  grid-row: 1;
}

.col.price {
  grid-area: price;
  grid-row: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class='grid'>
 <div class='col index'>No</div>
 <div class='col'>Color</div>
 <div class='col'>Size</div>
 <div class='col price'>Price</div>
 <div>1</div>
 <div>Red</div>
 <div>Large</div>
 <div>1,000</div>
</div>
```

The first dynamic column `Color` is 161px-width which is what I wanted, but the second one `Size` is not 161px-width which I want it to be.

Is it possible to make it by static css? Or should I use inline-style?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to set two 161px blocks for Columns? either Rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify this at the gird items level not the container level

```css
.grid {
  width: 290px;
  overflow-x: auto;

  display: grid;
}
.grid :not(.col) {
  grid-row: 2;
}
.col {
  width: 161px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.col.index {
  width: 80px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
.col.price {
  width: 210px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class='grid'>
 <div class='col index'>No</div>
 <div class='col'>Color</div>
 <div class='col'>Size</div>
 <div class='col price'>Price</div>
 <div>1</div>
 <div>Red</div>
 <div>Large</div>
 <div>1,000</div>
</div>
```